# Relationship between a ConnectedApp and Organizations

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps

What's the relationship between ConnectedApp and the Organizations they are defined in?

I have defined a ConnectedApp in one org (org 1) with API access enabled, and it seems that I can use the client_id and client_secret of that connected app to obtain an access token to a different organization (org 2) using an user account defined in Org 2.

Org 1 and Org 2 does not share the connected app in anyway? Is this behavior correct?

I was under the impression that ConnectedApp should only enable access to orgs in which the connected app is installed in. Is that understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A Connected App represents the "identity" of an application. For example, when you use the Data Loader, it uses a specific Connected App that's presumably hosted in Org 62, no matter which org you use it with. Doing this allows Salesforce to revoke access to a specific *application*, without preventing a user from logging in successfully.

You can think of this to be similar to how Facebook allows you to identify with various websites and games; each application gets a unique identifier that allows you, the user, to know which applications you're using, and to revoke access to a specific application without having to log out completely and/or change your password.

The first time a user uses an application in an org, it creates a limited Connected App that administrators can use to control or block access to a specific application, such as allowing only certain profiles to use it, or limit the data the application is allowed to access.

A Connected App exists in only one org, but can be used in any number of other orgs in order to enhance users' capabilities, such as logging Chatter Posts, importing or exporting data, etc.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox, it makes sense. But I can't find any trace of the Connected App in Org 2 (to which obtain and access token using an Org 2 user account), except for the Login history of the particular user. (Info: I'm using OAuth2 password flow to get the access token, and the user is an administrator account). Question is, how does Org 2 prevent my Connected App from accessing Org2's API?

Comment: @BuddhiP You should not be using the password flow other than for testing purposes. Still, to block it, they should be able to go to Setup > Manage Apps > Connected App OAuth Usage, and click the Block button to block it, or Install to install it and configure the permissions for the app.

Comment: Thanks again @sfdcfox. Is there any other recommend way to authenticate an External service to a  SF org, which need to call custom REST controller, if we can't expect for an interactive user to be available every time server need to talk to SF?

Comment: @BuddhiP You don't need to authenticate in realtime all the time if you have a connected app, just the first time. That's the one of the features of a connected app.

Comment: true, but I'm unable to allow that login even for the first time. These requests originate from a Backend console app, which does not have UI. Is JWT Bearer Token flow a better alternative?

Comment: @BuddhiP To be honest, no idea, I've never used JWT tokens. It may help, may not, but you'll probably want further support from someone that knows more than I.

Comment: @sdfcfox. Thank you sir! You have been an immense help nevertheless. To many people, and your reputation speaks for it. :)

Comment: @sfdcfox And what if we need to update some params of this connected app created many years ago in dev org, but no one remember what dev org was used? Is there any chance to find this dev org by only having consumerKey of connected app itself used in mobile app?

Comment: @wesaw I did see your other question, and unfortunately, this is one of those things I don't really know. I myself have a connected app I created for a desktop project I was working on, and now I can't find the org I created it in. As far as I know, the only real choice is to create a new connected app and try to not lose it. That said, have you tried contacting support? If there's a chance they can recover it, I'd love to know.

Comment: @sfdcfox Guys opened case in SF support but without any success. Trying doing the same myself, will let you know about the outcome of our adventure with support. Another thought we have, is that org id should be somehow reflected in consumer key to make it globally unique among all connected apps in the world. But no luck so far to reverse-engineer consumer key generation algorithm)

Comment: @sfdcfox SF support asked us to provide connected app id. Fortunately we were able to figure it out by installing connected app from OAuth Usage page in Setup area of one of our orgs (i.e. where mobile app's users have been logged in). After that SF support provided us with org id.

Comment: @sfdcfox After scanning our JIRA we discovered that org is actually one of our test sandboxes and it has been refreshed couple times since then, i.e. no connected app there anymore. At the same time, SF support confirmed that it's safe to use app even after org was decomissioned, since app was already copied/propagated to every SF instance and sort of live there (i.e. internally connected app is represented as 1gp managed package). Anyway, we are planning to create new connected app and slowly start switching our mobile users to it. At least we are not restricted in time.

Comment: @wesaw That's good to know. The moral of the story, of course, is to not create Connected Apps in a Sandbox or other non-permanent type of org.